# How to define correct Map<X,Y> type in typescript where Y will be any child class of Parent?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have some `Parent` class and amount of `Child` classes that extends parent.
I need to define `Map<sting,Y>` where `Y` can be any of `Child` classes.
If I try to define it as `Map<string, Parent>` I got transpilation error

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Parent'.  Property 'someParentMethod' is missing in
>   type 'typeof Child'.

As `Child` automatically inherits `someParentMethod` from `Parent` I don't re declare in `Child` class.
What is the correct way of declare needed `Map` argument type, so that it accepted any `Child` class instances?

Comment: Is the `Map` supposed to hold *instances* of `Child` or *constructors* of `Child`?   Please post the code that gives the error.  It looks like you are passing in a constructor where it expects an instance.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. The problem is exactly that I'm passing constructor, instead of instance.
I actually need to pass the constructors.
Would you be so kind, to tell ss there a way to define type so that it accepted constuctor of any `Child`. 
Example simplified code that raises mentioned error is below.
Thanks in advance.
`
class a {
 public x;
}

class b extends a {

}


let m:Map<string, a> = new Map([['a',b]]);
`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only missing a `typeof`.

```
class a { public x; someParentMethod: () => void }
class b extends a { }

let m: Map<string, typeof a> = new Map([['a', b]]);
```